# To get stage catkinized in Groovy

Tags: simulation, ros-groovy, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like `stage` is still dry in Groovy and one of our packages that we recently catkinized depends on it so that we can't release the package into ROS using `bloom`.

All of `stage`'s dependency looks wet (see attached snapshots of [rqt_dep](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_dep)). Because of possible simplicity, we're thinking that we might want to catkinize it. However, I can't seem to find so far its ROS package source repository. Where is it located? Or is [stage_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros) what we might want to backport into Groovy?

Please tell me what's the best option for us to get wet version of `stage` in Groovy. Thanks.

Result of rqt_dep. **Wet and dry**:
[image: image description]

**Dry only**:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87286/to-get-stage-catkinized-in-groovy/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At this point for your internal processes you could backport the version of stage from hydro, but for stability we should not switch the released version of stage in groovy.

We've had several attempts to do this sort of thing on released packages which have caused signifincant regressions and interruptions to users, which is why we have the development cycle with beta testing and only should do patch releases in the middle of a cycle.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0